# ng2-smart-table: Calculate other column value from custom renderComponent

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I have created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-smart-table-column-cal) for code.

I want to update value of `Total` column on change of `Quantity`. In custom component when I update `total` in data, it's not being updated in UI while data is being updated (I can see it in console).

It's specific problem with `ng2-smart-table`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `LocalDataSource` for source so that you can tell ng2-table that something has been changed and it should refresh the data `source.refresh()`

## Change in app.component.ts

```
source: LocalDataSource;
```

Change in setting

```
 quantity: {
        title: 'Quantity',
        type: 'custom',
        renderComponent: CustomComponent,
        sort: false,
        editable: true,
        onComponentInitFunction: (instance: any) => {
          instance.save.subscribe(row => {
            this.source.refresh();
          });
        }
      },
```

## Change in custom.compnent.ts

```
export class CustomComponent {

    rowData: any;

   @Output() save: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    onModelChange(table) {
        this.rowData.total = this.rowData.amount * this.rowData.price;
        this.save.emit(this.rowData);
    }
}
```

Working demo is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-smart-table-column-cal-m9nxpg

Comment: I guess you didn't save stackblitz. Can you please do that?

Comment: Also, you are right that could be done from `LocalDataSource` but when you call `this.source.refresh();`, it will loose focus of editable field because it will treat source as new.

Comment: Link is updated in answer. Yes, it will loose the focus that needs to be handled separately.

Comment: That's the problem, also in my opinion it's not good to refresh datasource on every change of `Input`.

Comment: I don't see any other option in ng2-smart-table to update the content. Even adding or removing any row also refresh the page.